# NetBeans + xdebug: How can I restart my PHP session every time I start the debugger?

Tags: php, netbeans, session-state, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a PHP website login system using NetBeans 7.0.1 and xdebug 2.1.0. I want to restart the PHP session every time I start the debugger (so that I'm always "logged out" when I go to debug). I thought of creating a new PHP file with `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` in it, so that I can restart the session each time I debug, but I'm wondering if there's a setting in xdebug to do this automatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no setting or functionality in Xdebug to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the login system files directly when you start the debugger, you could add the session destroy in the header and trigger it if a particular $_GET variable is set.

Then add that parameter to the URL you enter in the "Specify URL" window when you start a debug session.

Be Well,
Joe